# Uri Optional Parameter in Angular js

Tags: angularjs

I am not able to route to this url and also not able to find the reason why it's not working

```
.state('cities', {
            url: '/cities/?{couponCode}',
            templateUrl: '/scripts/app/templates/cities.html',
            controller: 'citiesController'
        })
```

Comment: Can you try `url: '/cities?couponCode'` and access by `#/cities?couponCode=abc`?

Comment: yes, I tried it still I am not able to access
 .state('cities', {
                url: '/cities?couponCode',
                templateUrl: '/scripts/app/templates/cities.html',
                controller: 'citiesController'
            })

Comment: Hi ,Thanks now I am able to access as the url parameter was also taking #/cities?couponCode=abc by default